# UTF-8 Special Characters in PHP/Codeigniter not displaying correctly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, utf-8

I am working on a friends website, he complained that he could not enter £ on his product pages, instead they were appearing as black square with ? in them (�)

I have been digging around in the code for 2 days now and am unable to find the culprit.

I have a MySQL DB with all the data in it. The DB and table/field are all set to: **utf8_general_ci**

Looking at a record in PHPMyAdmin, the record shoes £ as expected.

However, when looking at the front end, the £ displays as a black square with a question mark in side of it.

I read in multiple places that is due to the browser not knowing it is UTF-8 character so I checked and all pages contain the following in the  tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

The only way I can get it to display correctly is if I change the encoding via the browser to **ISO-8859-1** or ammend the above meta tag to reflect the ISO-8859-1:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

Is anybody able to help me with what to try next?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this to the variable while output

```
$var = "£";
echo utf8_encode($var);
```

and make sure your

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

is in the header

Comment: However now the £ is part of the URL as well, so when it gets queried it just does a 302 redirect back to the homepage.

Comment: The link now shows http://localhost/product-name-£ but when watch the network tab in Chrome after clicking the link it shows /product-name-%C2%A3 which is why it's having a meltdown. Where should I use urlencode. Sorry, CodeIgniter is new to me.

Comment: I think there is some other problem with the code, because chrome is doing url encoding for you. (i think £ == %C2%A3) not sure

Comment: Yeah, I googled it and that is the value for a £ symbol. Im guessing it needs  to be converted back to £ prior to it searching the database. :-/

Comment: You should not have to use utf8_encode; something else is going wrong.